# $x^y + y^x = x + y$ Solve for all possible positive integer $x$ and $y$

Tags: number-theory

I guess my questions would be how to even approach this question?
There are some obvious solutions for $x$ and $y$:

-If they're both equal to $1$

-If either one of them is equal to $1$

But how would I go about finding all possible solutions?

Comment: Hint: consider that if either of them is greater than $1$, then the left-hand side will get really big.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $x>1$ and $y>1$. Then $x^y>x$ and $y^x > y$ so $x^y+y^x > x+y$. So we must have $x=1$ or $y=1$.

But if either one is $1$, then equality holds : for example if $x=1$ then $x^y+y^x = 1+y$ and $x+y = 1+y$. Similarly if $y=1$.